# Yarn Workspaces with Webpack and Babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to set up Yarn Workspaces with Webpack and a React Client, but am having trouble getting the `babel-loader` to be honored. [Here is an example repo](https://github.com/chalupagrande/bug-report)

Essentially I set up a package as a "tools" package what contains all my development tools and can be imported int a package as I need it. [This pattern is outlined here](https://medium.com/trabe/monorepo-setup-with-lerna-and-yarn-workspaces-5d747d7c0e91). I tried to use this pattern as it seemed like a cleaner solution to dev tooling with yarn packages.

The article above mentions the use of using Webpack in a similar way, however I am unable to get the `client` package to compile correctly.

Running `yarn install` and then `yarn --cwd packages/client build` results in this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import App from './App'
|
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
|
```

I'm guessing this is because the package is not honoring my loaders/presets outlined in my `.babelrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Question 1: Is this pattern more work than it is worth?

Question 2: Why wont my react code compile?

Answer (score 2):

I had `.webpack.config.js` instead of `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: Closer than I got, I had "webconfig.config.js"! Thank you!